# Null Pointer Exception Error on queryInventoryAsync

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

I'm getting an Null Pointer Exception Error when calling the following method from In App Purchase. I tested on my phone and it seemed to work fine. However, on the ANRs & Crashes, I see people are getting the null pointer exception on this line

inv = queryInventory(querySkuDetails, moreItemSkus, moreSubsSkus);

Following is the code from the IAP sample code that I use in my app.

```
public void queryInventoryAsync(final boolean querySkuDetails, final List<String> moreItemSkus,
        final List<String> moreSubsSkus, final QueryInventoryFinishedListener listener)
    throws IabAsyncInProgressException {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    checkNotDisposed();
    checkSetupDone("queryInventory");
    flagStartAsync("refresh inventory");
    (new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            IabResult result = new IabResult(BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK, "Inventory refresh successful.");
            Inventory inv = null;
            try {
                inv = queryInventory(querySkuDetails, moreItemSkus, moreSubsSkus); // line where null pointer exception is return
            }
            catch (IabException ex) {
                result = ex.getResult();
            }

            flagEndAsync();

            final IabResult result_f = result;
            final Inventory inv_f = inv;
            if (!mDisposed && listener != null) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        listener.onQueryInventoryFinished(result_f, inv_f);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    })).start();
}
```

Here's the complete error that I'm seeing from ANRs & crashes

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.toksampleapp.util.IabHelper.queryPurchases 
   (IabHelper.java:945)
 at com.toksampleapp.util.IabHelper.queryInventory 
(IabHelper.java:624)
  at com.toksampleapp.util.IabHelper$2.run (IabHelper.java:698)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Please post complete stack trace from the logcat.

Comment: I posted the error that I see from ANRs & crashes.

Comment: `null pointer exception on this line

inv = queryInventory(querySkuDetails, moreItemSkus, moreSubsSkus);` ? I do not see that line in your 'complete' error. You did not post the full stacktrace i think. What is on line  (IabHelper.java:945)? Please find out which of your variables is null. `pointer==null`.

Comment: Yah, it is actually the complete trace which I thought was weird too because it has only 3 lines.       The line 945 is       Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, mContext.getPackageName(),
                    itemType, continueToken);

Comment: line 624 is int r = queryPurchases(inv, ITEM_TYPE_INAPP);

Comment: Then `mService==null` or `mContext==null`. Check before use and dont use if null. Also check those other variables.

Comment: thank you, I think that would fix the issue.